# Why is MySQLi Fetch Array returning null?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE hash = '" . $file . "'");
while($result = $query->fetch_array()) {
  $result[0] = $result['uploadr'];
  $result[1] = $result['name'];
}
```

This is the code for the query and fetching array, yet it returns null. Any ideas? By the way, I try to get the result using "$result[0]" and both "$result['uploadr'];". Any help with this?

Comment: does the query actually return results in mysql?

Comment: Yes, I did or die(mysqli_error()); and there were no errors; I also did the query in phpMyAdmin, and it returned the result.

Comment: What does `print_r($result)` look like? Results there?

Comment: If you're using MySQLi, use prepared statements

Comment: Also, this is unrelated to the question but be aware that using that function (especially the way you have it implemented) is probably pretty vulnerable to SQL-injection. Check out PDO

Comment: @Mattedgod, that didn't work.

Comment: @user1944331 What does "didn't work" mean? Error? Empty array? MySQLi documentation says it will return NULL if there are no more rows

Comment: @mattedgod Yes, it returned no result; sorry for not being specific. This is the query returned from phpMyAdmin. http://screencloud.net/v/i5Fn

Comment: @user1944331 haha that still isn't specific. Is there a reason you are re-assigning elements of the `$result` array? Why don't you try changing your query to something like `SELECT COUNT(1) as ct ...` rather than `SELECT *` so you guarantee a result and can see how many rows are returned

Comment: @mattedgod It still returns null when I use "SELECT COUNT(1)"; would you mind seeing via join.me? https://secure.join.me/436-924-239

Comment: @mattegod helped me fix this; thanks man!

Answer (score -2):

Do not reassign your array. Just use `$result= query->fetch_assoc()` and retrieve them like this:

```
$upload = $result['uploadr'];
echo $upload;
```

To make your query solid against attacks you should use a prepared statement:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE hash = ?"
if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($query))
    {
        echo "Prepared Failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
    }
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $file))
        {
            echo "Bind Failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
        }
        if (!$stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "Execution Failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
            }
            if (!$results = $stmt->get_results())
                {
                    echo "No Results where found: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
                }
                while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $upload = $row['uploadr'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    echo $upload."<br>";
                    echo $name;
                }
        $stmt -> close();
        $db -> close();
```

Comment: @RomanNewaza I do not write with the If(!). I just put that in so he could debug his problem step by step. but thanks for your input.

Comment: You should use exceptions instead. It is possible to set them using [`mysqli_report()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php), with `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`.